# react-native-camera How to detect if camera2 API is available on the device?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I am building a react native application in which I am using react-native-camera component for creating a custom camera component. When I enable **useCamera2Api** prop in the **RNCamera** component it works on some devices but on some devices it breaks the application. Is there a way to detect if camera2 API is available on the device or not? Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: did you come across any solutions?

Comment: No, I end up building the native camera component and using it in react native.